# Rails Devise:Doorkeeper: Authentication, updating fields (devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth-2.0, devise, doorkeeper

How can I update the devise fields when doorkeeper is used as authorization provider using oauth.

My Authenticate method looks like this using Devise.

```
def authenticate(email, password)
  user = User.find_for_authentication(email: email)
  if user.active_for_authentication?
    user = user.try(:valid_password?, password) ? user : nil
  else
    user = nil
  end
  user
end
```

However, I would like to update the corresponding device user fields for successful authentications. Such fields include:

```
sign_in_count
current_sign_in_at
current_sign_in_ip
last_sign_in_ip
failed_attempts
etc
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using trackable module from devise, I amable to update fields:

```
resource_owner_from_credentials do |_routes|
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
      user.update_tracked_fields!(request) unless user.nil?
    end
end
```